# Virtuoso. Math functions in SPARQL

Tags: math, sparql, semantic-web, virtuoso

I know that SPARQL defines a limited set of math functions which certainly don't include trigonometry functions. As a semantic database, I have Virtuoso, and I want to use Virtuoso's [trigonometry functions](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_acos.html)

```
SELECT sin(90) WHERE {?s ?p ?o}
```

As the exception I get 
`SPARQL compiler, line 1: syntax error at 'sin' before '('`

My question is how to properly use the function?

Comment: Have you tried `select (sin(90) as ?sine) where ...`? Function results need to be bound to something in SPARQL.

Comment: just did, got the same result

Answer (score 4):

As it turned out the prefix `bif` should be used to make it work, here is the working example of the query

```
SELECT bif:sin(90)
WHERE {?s ?p ?o}
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: nitpicking, but if you just want to execute bif:sin(90), the following is simpler:  SELECT big:sin(90) WHERE {} .

Answer (score 0):

You need to qualify the function with the `bif:` prefix. 
Example:

```
SELECT bif:sin(90) WHERE {?s ?p ?o} LIMIT 1
```